# MySQL copy hierarchical data and maintain relationship

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I need to copy data within a tab that has hierarchical relationships and maintain the relation within the new data.

I have a table "site_content", the table has thousands of rows and the data in the table is quite extent. Here are the reduced table structure and column data for an example.

```
  CREATE TABLE `site_content` (
 `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `site_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `parent` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
 `parent_orig_id` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
 `content_text` text,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`));

INSERT INTO `site_content` (`id`, `site_id`, `parent`, `parent_orig_id`, `content_text`) VALUES(1, 76, 0, NULL, '');
INSERT INTO `site_content` (`id`, `site_id`, `parent`, `parent_orig_id`, `content_text`) VALUES(2, 76, 1, NULL, 'some content');
INSERT INTO `site_content` (`id`, `site_id`, `parent`, `parent_orig_id`, `content_text`) VALUES(3, 76, 1, NULL, 'some content');
INSERT INTO `site_content` (`id`, `site_id`, `parent`, `parent_orig_id`, `content_text`) VALUES(4, 76, 1, NULL, 'some content');
INSERT INTO `site_content` (`id`, `site_id`, `parent`, `parent_orig_id`, `content_text`) VALUES(5, 76, 1, NULL, 'some content');
INSERT INTO `site_content` (`id`, `site_id`, `parent`, `parent_orig_id`, `content_text`) VALUES(6, 76, 1, NULL, 'some content');
INSERT INTO `site_content` (`id`, `site_id`, `parent`, `parent_orig_id`, `content_text`) VALUES(7, 76, 2, NULL, 'some content');
INSERT INTO `site_content` (`id`, `site_id`, `parent`, `parent_orig_id`, `content_text`) VALUES(8, 76, 3, NULL, 'some content');
INSERT INTO `site_content` (`id`, `site_id`, `parent`, `parent_orig_id`, `content_text`) VALUES(9, 76, 3, NULL, 'some content');
INSERT INTO `site_content` (`id`, `site_id`, `parent`, `parent_orig_id`, `content_text`) VALUES(11, 76, 9, NULL, 'some content');
INSERT INTO `site_content` (`id`, `site_id`, `parent`, `parent_orig_id`, `content_text`) VALUES(12, 76, 9, NULL, 'some content');
INSERT INTO `site_content` (`id`, `site_id`, `parent`, `parent_orig_id`, `content_text`) VALUES(13, 76, 9, NULL, 'some content');
INSERT INTO `site_content` (`id`, `site_id`, `parent`, `parent_orig_id`, `content_text`) VALUES(14, 76, 4, NULL, 'some content');
INSERT INTO `site_content` (`id`, `site_id`, `parent`, `parent_orig_id`, `content_text`) VALUES(15, 76, 4, NULL, 'some content');
INSERT INTO `site_content` (`id`, `site_id`, `parent`, `parent_orig_id`, `content_text`) VALUES(28, 76, 4, NULL, 'some content');
INSERT INTO `site_content` (`id`, `site_id`, `parent`, `parent_orig_id`, `content_text`) VALUES(29, 76, 4, NULL, 'some content');
INSERT INTO `site_content` (`id`, `site_id`, `parent`, `parent_orig_id`, `content_text`) VALUES(30, 76, 5, NULL, 'some content');
INSERT INTO `site_content` (`id`, `site_id`, `parent`, `parent_orig_id`, `content_text`) VALUES(32, 76, 5, NULL, 'some content');
INSERT INTO `site_content` (`id`, `site_id`, `parent`, `parent_orig_id`, `content_text`) VALUES(36, 76, 41, NULL, 'some content');
INSERT INTO `site_content` (`id`, `site_id`, `parent`, `parent_orig_id`, `content_text`) VALUES(41, 76, 32, NULL, 'some content');
INSERT INTO `site_content` (`id`, `site_id`, `parent`, `parent_orig_id`, `content_text`) VALUES(42, 76, 32, NULL, 'some content');
INSERT INTO `site_content` (`id`, `site_id`, `parent`, `parent_orig_id`, `content_text`) VALUES(43, 76, 41, NULL, 'some content');
INSERT INTO `site_content` (`id`, `site_id`, `parent`, `parent_orig_id`, `content_text`) VALUES(44, 76, 41, NULL, 'some content');
INSERT INTO `site_content` (`id`, `site_id`, `parent`, `parent_orig_id`, `content_text`) VALUES(45, 76, 41, NULL, 'some content');
INSERT INTO `site_content` (`id`, `site_id`, `parent`, `parent_orig_id`, `content_text`) VALUES(46, 76, 41, NULL, 'some content');
INSERT INTO `site_content` (`id`, `site_id`, `parent`, `parent_orig_id`, `content_text`) VALUES(47, 76, 41, NULL, 'some content');
INSERT INTO `site_content` (`id`, `site_id`, `parent`, `parent_orig_id`, `content_text`) VALUES(48, 76, 41, NULL, 'some content');
INSERT INTO `site_content` (`id`, `site_id`, `parent`, `parent_orig_id`, `content_text`) VALUES(49, 76, 41, NULL, 'some content');
INSERT INTO `site_content` (`id`, `site_id`, `parent`, `parent_orig_id`, `content_text`) VALUES(50, 76, 42, NULL, 'some content');
INSERT INTO `site_content` (`id`, `site_id`, `parent`, `parent_orig_id`, `content_text`) VALUES(51, 76, 42, NULL, 'some content');
```

I need to copy the "site 76" rows within the table, so I use this query to copy the table and also to give me the original parent child relationship information in the 'parent_orig_id' column.

```
INSERT INTO site_content (`id`, `site_id`, `parent`, `parent_orig_id`, `content_text`)
SELECT NULL, "200", `parent`, `id`, `content_text` FROM site_content 
WHERE `site_id` = '76';
```

I now have the data for site "76" copied in the table as site "200"

How can I update the new site 200 rows to have the same relationship as the site 76 rows? For example row "1" is the parent of rows "2, 3, 4, 5, 6".

Row "2" for site 200 is now row id "53" and thinks that its parent is still row "1" based off of the "parent" column from the copy. How can I update the column "parent" in the copied rows to now reflect the new relationship as it is site 200. The "parent_orig_id" column hold the row id for the original hierarchical relationship.

I can see that if I do the query what I need to update. I would like to do this in SQL if possible.

```
select a.id current_row, a.parent as current_parent, b.id AS new_parent
  from site_content a, site_content b
 where b.parent_orig_id = a.parent AND a.site_id = '200' AND b.site_id = '200'
```

Comment: Can you explain why Row "2" for site 200 is now row id "53"?  Why isn't it the same as in the old table?

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize that you are copying into the same table.  I think I can help you now.

Comment: Row 2 is the second row in the copied data

Comment: Roger.  My confusion is eliminated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to maintain not only the `parent_orig_id`, but also the `orig_id`.  Since you've gone half the distance using the strategy of having columns in your table for this, I'll continue in that direction.  Like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `site_content` (
`id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`site_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`parent` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
`orig_id` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
`parent_orig_id` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
`content_text` text,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`));

INSERT INTO `site_content` (`id`, `site_id`, `parent`, `orig_id`,  `parent_orig_id`, `content_text`) VALUES(1, 76, 0, NULL, '');
INSERT INTO `site_content` (`id`, `site_id`, `parent`, `orig_id`,  `parent_orig_id`, `content_text`) VALUES(2, 76, 1, NULL, 'some content');
INSERT INTO `site_content` (`id`, `site_id`, `parent`, `orig_id`,  `parent_orig_id`, `content_text`) VALUES(3, 76, 1, NULL, 'some content');
INSERT INTO `site_content` (`id`, `site_id`, `parent`, `orig_id`,  `parent_orig_id`, `content_text`) VALUES(4, 76, 1, NULL, 'some content');
INSERT INTO `site_content` (`id`, `site_id`, `parent`, `orig_id`,  `parent_orig_id`, `content_text`) VALUES(5, 76, 1, NULL, 'some content');
INSERT INTO `site_content` (`id`, `site_id`, `parent`, `orig_id`,  `parent_orig_id`, `content_text`) VALUES(6, 76, 1, NULL, 'some content');
INSERT INTO `site_content` (`id`, `site_id`, `parent`, `orig_id`,  `parent_orig_id`, `content_text`) VALUES(7, 76, 2, NULL, 'some content');
INSERT INTO `site_content` (`id`, `site_id`, `parent`, `orig_id`,  `parent_orig_id`, `content_text`) VALUES(8, 76, 3, NULL, 'some content');
INSERT INTO `site_content` (`id`, `site_id`, `parent`, `orig_id`,  `parent_orig_id`, `content_text`) VALUES(9, 76, 3, NULL, 'some content');
INSERT INTO `site_content` (`id`, `site_id`, `parent`, `orig_id`,  `parent_orig_id`, `content_text`) VALUES(11, 76, 9, NULL, 'some content');
INSERT INTO `site_content` (`id`, `site_id`, `parent`, `orig_id`,  `parent_orig_id`, `content_text`) VALUES(12, 76, 9, NULL, 'some content');
INSERT INTO `site_content` (`id`, `site_id`, `parent`, `orig_id`,  `parent_orig_id`, `content_text`) VALUES(13, 76, 9, NULL, 'some content');
INSERT INTO `site_content` (`id`, `site_id`, `parent`, `orig_id`,  `parent_orig_id`, `content_text`) VALUES(14, 76, 4, NULL, 'some content');
INSERT INTO `site_content` (`id`, `site_id`, `parent`, `orig_id`,  `parent_orig_id`, `content_text`) VALUES(15, 76, 4, NULL, 'some content');
INSERT INTO `site_content` (`id`, `site_id`, `parent`, `orig_id`,  `parent_orig_id`, `content_text`) VALUES(28, 76, 4, NULL, 'some content');
INSERT INTO `site_content` (`id`, `site_id`, `parent`, `orig_id`,  `parent_orig_id`, `content_text`) VALUES(29, 76, 4, NULL, 'some content');
INSERT INTO `site_content` (`id`, `site_id`, `parent`, `orig_id`,  `parent_orig_id`, `content_text`) VALUES(30, 76, 5, NULL, 'some content');
INSERT INTO `site_content` (`id`, `site_id`, `parent`, `orig_id`,  `parent_orig_id`, `content_text`) VALUES(32, 76, 5, NULL, 'some content');
INSERT INTO `site_content` (`id`, `site_id`, `parent`, `orig_id`,  `parent_orig_id`, `content_text`) VALUES(36, 76, 41, NULL, 'some content');
INSERT INTO `site_content` (`id`, `site_id`, `parent`, `orig_id`,  `parent_orig_id`, `content_text`) VALUES(41, 76, 32, NULL, 'some content');
INSERT INTO `site_content` (`id`, `site_id`, `parent`, `orig_id`,  `parent_orig_id`, `content_text`) VALUES(42, 76, 32, NULL, 'some content');
INSERT INTO `site_content` (`id`, `site_id`, `parent`, `orig_id`,  `parent_orig_id`, `content_text`) VALUES(43, 76, 41, NULL, 'some content');
INSERT INTO `site_content` (`id`, `site_id`, `parent`, `orig_id`,  `parent_orig_id`, `content_text`) VALUES(44, 76, 41, NULL, 'some content');
INSERT INTO `site_content` (`id`, `site_id`, `parent`, `orig_id`,  `parent_orig_id`, `content_text`) VALUES(45, 76, 41, NULL, 'some content');
INSERT INTO `site_content` (`id`, `site_id`, `parent`, `orig_id`,  `parent_orig_id`, `content_text`) VALUES(46, 76, 41, NULL, 'some content');
INSERT INTO `site_content` (`id`, `site_id`, `parent`, `orig_id`,  `parent_orig_id`, `content_text`) VALUES(47, 76, 41, NULL, 'some content');
INSERT INTO `site_content` (`id`, `site_id`, `parent`, `orig_id`,  `parent_orig_id`, `content_text`) VALUES(48, 76, 41, NULL, 'some content');
INSERT INTO `site_content` (`id`, `site_id`, `parent`, `orig_id`,  `parent_orig_id`, `content_text`) VALUES(49, 76, 41, NULL, 'some content');
INSERT INTO `site_content` (`id`, `site_id`, `parent`, `orig_id`,  `parent_orig_id`, `content_text`) VALUES(50, 76, 42, NULL, 'some content');
INSERT INTO `site_content` (`id`, `site_id`, `parent`, `orig_id`,  `parent_orig_id`, `content_text`) VALUES(51, 76, 42, NULL, 'some content');


INSERT INTO `site_content` (`id`, `site_id`, `parent`, `orig_id`,  `parent_orig_id`, `content_text`)
SELECT NULL, "200", NULL, `orig_id`, `parent_orig_id`, `content_text` FROM site_content 
WHERE `site_id` = '76';

UPDATE site_content AS sc_target 
LEFT JOIN site_content AS sc_source 
ON sc_source.parent_orig_id = sc_target.parent 
SET sc_target.parent = sc_source.id where sc_target.site_id = "200"
```

Comment: Sorry my brain is melting down currently. The data already exists in a DB and I am copying a portion of the data. I am copying the rows within the same table to be used for another "site" with the ID of 200.

This table is used to display data based on the site id.

Comment: Roger.  I'm reading you now.  I think we'll have this licked in a jiffy if you hang with me.  Give me a response to my answer if there's any trouble.

Comment: Please, greetings and signatures are not to be used on SO posts. Ta

Comment: @TomHaws - You got me on the right track, I think you mis understood what I was looking for. This was the solution that worked for me.

Comment: UPDATE `site_content` AS sc_target
    LEFT JOIN `site_content` AS sc_source ON
    sc_source.`parent_orig_id` = sc_target.`parent`
    SET sc_target.`parent` = sc_source.`id`
    where sc_target.`site_id` = "200"

Comment: Awesome.  Thanks.  I'll edit my answer with your final solution.